# Initial SessionFactory creation failed.java.lang.ClassFormatError

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Error in Console:-

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/transaction/SystemException
```

Hello 
 I am building a  standalone Java Application with Main Method which connects to the database using Hibernate and writes to a file on C drive as well.

I have added all the libraries to the class path using Java Build Path configuration and user libraries. But I keep getting this error ...I have also added the javaee jar from the `glassfish` server libraries but that has also not solved the problem. I also have the `jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.Jar` added to my class path.

Please advise as I am not using Maven as yet ???

Here are the jars in my build path-

```
-antlr
-c3p0
-commons-collections
-commons-logging
-commong-logging-api
-dom4j
-hibernate-c3p0
-hibernate-commons-annotation
-hibernate-core
-hibernate-entitymanager
-hibernate-envers
-hibernate-jpa
-javaee-api-6.0jar
-javaassist
-jboss-logging
-jboss-transaction-api
-jms
-log4j
-lucene-core
-MySQL-connector
-slf4j
-javaee.jar
```

Any help would be truly appreciated .. I am just lost on what is going on ?

Comment: Please add you hibernate configuration. Most probably you have configured Hibernate to use JTA transaction while not running on a server.

Comment: c.s The same project works fine on another machine where I have Java 7 and Oracle oepe package with Weblogic server.. Here I am using Java 6 and server is separate and is WAS 8.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure you have 2 different versions for the same class. check your jars.

Comment: Hi Varun..All my jars are the same as attached in a list here . They are all from the Hibernate 4.1.5 release ...Please suggest which one couldbe duplicate as I have been looking at it since yesterday and I am unable to figure out what is wron ?

Comment: I dont think you need javaee-api.jar, try removing it and replace javaee.jar from oracle website. I hope it will solve your problem. Although javaee.jar from glassfish lib seems fine but still try.

Comment: I guess you only had to remove javaee-api.jar?

Comment: That jar contains no implementation, consider it as only a jar you can compile your code with, thats why it failed at runtime. have fun coding.